# if statement in render

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, error-messages

I have the following piece of code.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!AuthorModel.saveAuthorList}" id="saveButton" value="Save"  rerender="pageblocktableid"/>
```

My requirement is that I want to refresh the entire page if x field is not null. If x field is null then only pageblocktableid is rendered.(Because otherwise the error message is not being displayed as I had to write return null) Is this possible to do so?

Comment: where is the piece of the code?

Comment: @Rimii by code that was mean all page code. Basic idea would be to try formula in rerender like `rerender="{!IF(ISNULL(X),'pageblocktableid','allpage')} "`

Answer (score 0):

You can use two command buttons and use `rendered` attribute to display one at a time. One will rerender `pageblock` and other will refresh the page:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!AuthorModel.saveAuthorList}" id="saveButton" value="Save"  rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(x),false,true)}" rerender="pageblocktableid"/>


<apex:commandButton action="{!AuthorModel.saveAuthorList}" id="saveButton" value="Save" rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(x),true,false)}"  />
```